# How can I use getInstance in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-reflect

I'm unable to use `createInstance()`. For example, `Foo::class.createInstance()`

I have a gradle project using Kotlin 1.3.70 `kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.70"` plugin. and have `implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))` and `implementation(kotlin("reflect"))` in my dependencies.

Does anyone know why this function appears to be missing?

I have a function that receives a `classType: KClass<Foo>` and I want to create a instance of `Foo` using the noarg constructor.

Comment: You need a Java Class instance instead of a kotlin class instance: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/java-class.html

Comment: Are you actually looking for `createInstance()`?

Comment: @Tenfour04 Oops yes, that is what I meant I just made a mistake when I wrote the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the Kotlin plugin version and deleted by gradle cache and now it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

To use Java reflection (like `newInstance()`) you need to [access the corresponding Java class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#getclass):

```
fun createInstance(classType: KClass<Foo>): Foo = classType.java.newInstance()
```

But Kotlin provides [createInstance()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/create-instance.html) as better alternative for that use case:

> Creates a new instance of the class, calling a constructor which either has no parameters or all parameters of which are optional.

```
fun createInstance(classType: KClass<Foo>): Foo = classType.createInstance()
```

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, my original post meant to ask why I couldn't use `createInstance()`, I just accidentally wrote `getInstance()`

Comment: And that means... what? Sorry, now I no longer understand what your actual question is.